# how to access information of particular user from firebase firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am new to firebase. I created the collection users having fields id, email, user_name and image_url. I have added records to the collection through registration as well. But i don't know how to  access the records of logged in user to include the current user's record in my application.

[image]

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: What does *i am having problem* mean specifically? Where's the code you're having difficulty with? Please update the question and we'll take a look.

Answer (score 2):

```
 final _fireStore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
 String imageURL ;
 String email;
 String imageURL ;

 await _fireStore
          .collection('users')
          .doc(userID)
          .get()
          .then((DocumentSnapshot snapShot) {
        if (snapShot.exists) {
            imageURL = snapShot.data()['img_url'];
            email= snapShot.data()['email'];
            user_name= snapShot.data()['user_name'];
            print('Done Fitching Data From FireStore');
            print(imageURL);
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering the entitled question and taking consideration fo your database schema this is how you can read a specific user from database.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(userDocumentId).get();
```

Where userDocumentId can be something like: "QW9y2GzxJi..."